# Ordering records from `has_many through, -> { distinct }` by an associated value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm using a `SELECT DISTINCT` and having issues trying to order my results by an associated value. Take this example (in Rails):

I have a `Cook` model with a distinct `customers` association:

```
has_many :customers, -> { distinct }, through: :orders, source: :user
```

It's distinct because I only want to count customers once, even if they have multiple orders.

The generated SQL for this is:

```
> cook.customers.to_sql
=> "SELECT DISTINCT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"
 INNER JOIN \"orders\" ON \"users\".\"id\" = \"orders\".\"user_id\"
 INNER JOIN \"meals\" ON \"orders\".\"meal_id\" = \"meals\".\"id\"
 WHERE \"meals\".\"cook_id\" = 1"
```

This works fine! (the `orders` table is associated through `meals` but feel free to ignore)

I want to order this list of customers by the most recent `created_at` value of the *orders* of those customers. But when I do this, I get an error:

```
cook.customers.order('orders.created_at DESC').to_sql
=> "SELECT DISTINCT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"
    INNER JOIN \"orders\" ON \"users\".\"id\" = \"orders\".\"user_id\"
    INNER JOIN \"meals\" ON \"orders\".\"meal_id\" = \"meals\".\"id        \"WHERE \"meals\".\"cook_id\" = 1  ORDER BY orders.created_at DESC"
  > cook.customers.order('orders.created_at DESC')
  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
  LINE 1: ...eals"."id" WHERE "meals"."cook_id" = $1  ORDER BY orders.cre...
```

Even if I explicitly join the tables (don't think I should need to because of `has_many through`), this still doesn't work.

```
cook.customers.joins(:orders).order('orders.created_at DESC').to_sql
=> "SELECT DISTINCT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" INNER JOIN \"orders\" \"orders_users\" ON \"orders_users\".\"user_id\" = \"users\".\"id\" INNER JOIN \"orders\" ON \"users\".\"id\" = \"orders\".\"user_id\" INNER JOIN \"meals\" ON \"orders\".\"meal_id\" = \"meals\".\"id\" WHERE \"meals\".\"cook_id\" = 1  ORDER BY orders.created_at DESC"
```

Any clues? I'm looking for a solution that will return an ActiveRecord relation (so no using `sort_by`), because I plan on chaining additional queries to this.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked. My model Apartment.rb has default scope ordering.

This doesn't work

```
has many :apartments
has_many :buildings, -> {distinct}, through: :apartments
```

This does

```
has many :apartments
has_many :buildings, through: :apartments

def buildings
  super.uniq
end
```

Comment: Using `.uniq` changes the the object from an ActiveRecord_Relation to an Array. This may not be ideal.

Comment: you are right. In my case, it was enough, I didn't needed the relations, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @JuanJoséRamírez Thank you! You saved me from hours of misery.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to manually specify the join conditions, you could do it by using `includes` and ActiveRecord will take care of the join conditions.

```
cook.customers.includes(:orders).order('orders.created_at DESC').references(:orders).to_sql
```

Comment: This actually yields the same error I was getting before: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`.